# PHP to Powershell script

Tags: php, powershell

I don't know much about PHP, but I've inherited a PHP script that I would like to convert to powershell.  I'm not sure if this is possible. But it looks like the script is getting a list of products as XML from a service.  It is then doing some cr/lf stripping, swapping a few quote characters, and then converting the xml to json.  Seems pretty straight forward.  I'm not very knowledgeable on powershell either, so I was hoping this would be a simple task for someone here.

```
<?php
    $fileContents= file_get_contents("http://svc.mysite.com/api/GetItems");

    $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);

    $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));

    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);

    $map = json_decode(json_encode($simpleXml));

    print json_encode($map->item);
?>
```

Here is a sample of the XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items xmlns="http://svc.tricorbraun.com/api/GetItems" version="1">
    <item><ItemID>000072</ItemID><ItemName>Dropper Tip Closure</ItemName><ItemGroup>Closures</ItemGroup><Shape>Round</Shape><Style>Fitment/Plug</Style></item>
    <item><ItemID>000182</ItemID><ItemName>28-480, P/P Push and Turn Closure</ItemName><ItemGroup>Closures</ItemGroup><Shape>Round</Shape><Style>Child Resistant</Style></item>
    <item><ItemID>000187</ItemID><ItemName>28-480, P/P Child Resistant Closure</ItemName><ItemGroup>Closures</ItemGroup><Shape>Round</Shape><Style>Child Resistant</Style></item>
    <item><ItemID>000190</ItemID><ItemName>28mm SPEC, P/P Dispensing Closure</ItemName><ItemGroup>Closures</ItemGroup><Shape>Round</Shape><Style>Dispensing</Style></item>
</items>
```

I came up with this, but if fails with an 'Unexpected namespace error'

```
    $doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$memStream = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream
$jsonWriter = [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonReaderWriterFactory]::CreateJsonWriter($memStream)

$doc.Load("http://svc.mysite.com/api/GetItems")
$doc.Save($jsonWriter)
$bytes = $memStream.ToArray()

[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes,0,$bytes.Length)
Write-Output $jsonWriter.ToString()
```

Comment: If you don't know either language/system it sounds like you need a freelancer, not a Q&A site.

Comment: I'm not the one making the requirements.  We've subcontracted the work out and received this PHP. We explicitly asked for powershell.  If it had been more complex, I wouldn't have submitted it here.  But if need be I'll figure it out on my own. Shouldn't need a free lancer.

Comment: Sounds like your subcontractor needs a foot roasting until he coughs up the goods specified.

Comment: The case being made by the contractor is that it can't be done easily with PowerShell.  I'm attempting to prove him wrong.  I started on a solution but ran into a few issues, so I reached out here.  However, I didn't expect the negative feedback and refusal of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to see what the reply is from this line:

```
$fileContents= file_get_contents("http://svc.mysite.com/api/GetItems");
```

Can you run the following in PowerShell and throw the results up on PasteBin or someplace?

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://svc.mysite.com/api/GetItems" | 
  Export-CLIXMl C:\temp\pathTo.XML
```

Once you've done that, the general tasks are to strip these chars :"\n", "\r", "\t", which is easy, and to replace double quotes with single, which is easy. PowerShell has a ConvertFrom-Json command, which makes that aspect easy too.

If you reply back with the sample output from the PowerShell code I've given above, I can help you work out the rest.

---

Thanks for replying with the full file type.

Assuming we have the .xml output in a .xml text file, this process will give you JSON objects, all with PowerShell.  It's really quite simple.

```
[xml]$string = get-content C:\temp\Pathto.xml
$string.items.Item  | Select-Object Item*,Shape,Style | ConvertTo-Json
```

**Output**

```
[
{
    "ItemID":  "000072",
    "ItemName":  "Dropper Tip Closure",
    "ItemGroup":  "Closures",
    "Shape":  "Round",
    "Style":  "Fitment/Plug"
},
{
    "ItemID":  "000182",
    "ItemName":  "28-480, P/P Push and Turn Closure",
    "ItemGroup":  "Closures",
    "Shape":  "Round",
    "Style":  "Child Resistant"
},
{
    "ItemID":  "000187",
    "ItemName":  "28-480, P/P Child Resistant Closure",
    "ItemGroup":  "Closures",
    "Shape":  "Round",
    "Style":  "Child Resistant"
},
{
    "ItemID":  "000190",
    "ItemName":  "28mm SPEC, P/P Dispensing Closure",
    "ItemGroup":  "Closures",
    "Shape":  "Round",
    "Style":  "Dispensing"
}
]
```

I don't work with JSOn on a daily basis, but that sure looks like a valid JSON envelope and content to me, and it validates on http://jsonlint.com/

One other thing.  You can most likely replace the first line with

```
[xml]$string = Invoke-WebRequest "http://svc.mysite.com/api/GetItems"
```

Comment: I have shared the xml.

Comment: I'm updating my other reply with the full convertto-Json process.

Comment: I think that's enough for me to work through it. Thanks.